# Set of natural numbers that sum to 2023 having the maximum product.

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization

Suppose I have a multiset of $n$ positive integers $S$ such that $\sum_{s \in S}s = 2023$ and $\prod_{s\in S}s$ is maximum. Then I need to determine the maximum value of this product.

**My work**:

Denote by $s_r$ the $r$th element of $S$. First, I use the AM-GM inequality and hence obtain that: $
\frac{2023}{n} \geq {\left(s_1\cdot s_2\cdot s_3 \cdots s_n\right)}^{\frac{1}{n}}.$

For the maximum to be achieved, $s_r = \frac{2023}{n} \ \ \ \forall \ r \leq n$, each of which I call $s$. Hence, $n = \frac{2023}{s}$.

So, I need to maximise $\prod_{s \in S} s = s^{n} = s^{\frac{2023}{s}}.$

Therefore, $s^n$ is maximised when: $\ln(s) = 1$

Hence, $s^n$ is maximised when $s = e$.

So I suppose that we can use the integer $3$ which is closest to $e$ and use it fill up the set $S$. But $2023$ is not divisible by $3$, so all of $s \in S$ can not be $3$. Clearly, $674$ $3$s can be used and $1$ $1$s can be used, hence giving the optimum product to be $3^{674}$.

My questions are: Is my argument for this problem correct? Is the usage of $3$ in order to maximise the product justified by the argument that it is closest to $e$? Can the use of derivatives be avoided?

Any help and insight will be appreciated.

**Edit**: $S$ was supposed to be a multiset — not a set. I apologize for any confusions caused. Nevertheless, those answers which worked with $S$ as a set are still very helpful to me and other users for they answer a similar question. So I encourage not deleting them.

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4168162/42969

Comment: Whoever asked you this probably got it from [this recent MindYourDecisions video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-UF8JlqZ_c) about the same question from the 1976 Math Olympiad.

Comment: 1. Do you mean "set" or "multiset"?  You say "set", but your examples suggest you might mean "multiset".  2. What is the context where you encountered this?  Can you credit the source where you saw it?  (For instance, this might help resolve ambiguities.)

Comment: @BlueRaja, Oh! I did not know of that, but the problem is essentially the same then.

Comment: @D.W., a friend of mine gave me this question. I’m not sure if repeated elements are allowed or not. I actually did not pay much attention to the usage of the word “set”.

Comment: You will need to decide whether you want answers that allow repeated elements, or that disallow them.  You are the only one who can decide what you want.

Comment: In maximizing the product s^n, I did not follow how that implied ln(s) = 1. (Call it a senior moment so as to be kind!) Not that I doubt the result, and it is well-known that s has to be e for this... but I just want to know what step I missed. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @MichaelEcker, I simply equated the derivative of $s^n$ to $0$, which means $-2023s^{2023/(s-2)}\cdot (log(s)-1) = 0$

Comment: Oops... thanks... I had an error in the derivative, but I confirmed your result. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic is correct in finding the approximate value, but you need a bit more to get to the bottom of it. First, by inspection:

$$
\begin{matrix}
n & \text{max prod}\\ 
1 & 1 = 1\\ 
2 & 2 = 2\\ 
3 & 3 = 3\\ 
4 & 2 \cdot 2 = 4\\ 
5 & 2 \cdot 3 = 6\\ 
6 & 3 \cdot 3 = 9
\end{matrix}
$$

So we can see that this part follows for $n>1$

$$ P(n) = \begin{cases}
3^k & \text{ if } n= 3k\\ 
2^2\cdot3^{k-1} = 4\cdot3^{k-1} & \text{ if } n = 3k+1 \\
2\cdot3^k & \text{ if } n = 3k+2\\ 
\end{cases}$$

Assume it is correct for every $n<k$. Now, assume we have created a maximal product for $k+1$ that contains a factor $a_m \leq k$ greater than $3$. However, in that case, $a_m$ could be replaced by its maximal product $P(a_m)$ containing only $2$'s and $3$'s getting a larger product. Therefore we cannot have any factors greater than $3$.

(Let us discuss having $1$ as a possible factor. If we have two $1$'s in the product, we can replace it with $2$, so we can have eventually only one $1$. If we have anywhere either $2$ or $3$ we can add this $1$ to it and get a larger product. Now, we are sure that we have only $2$'s and $3$'s in the product.)

Suppose we have more than two $2$'s. Three of them are giving $6$ as a sum and $8$ as a product, but this has a replacement in the form of $3\cdot3$ and this is $9$ as a product. So we cannot have more than two $2$'s.

So it remains to have zero one or two $2$'s and the rest are $3$'s. Finally, if it is there, we cannot replace $2 \cdot 2$ by anything since we would either introduce $1$'s or we would have to introduce factors greater than $3$. This is because $ 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot 3 $ with any number of already available $3$'s including zero is the maximal product for the corresponding sum, i.e. it cannot be improved. Equally any selection in the form of $ 2 \cdot 3 \cdot ... \cdot 3$ and $3 \cdot ... \cdot 3$, proving that if we have two $2$'s and the rest are $3$'s that is the best possible choice.  Notice that $4$ is just a synonym for $2 \cdot 2$ since it changes the notation not the result either as a sum or a product.

This leads again to the general solution in the form of $n>1$

$$ P(n) = \begin{cases}
3^k & \text{ if } n= 3k\\ 
2^2\cdot3^{k-1} = 4\cdot3^{k-1} & \text{ if } n = 3k+1 \\
2\cdot3^k & \text{ if } n = 3k+2\\ 
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 9):

That is very close to ideal, but the 1 can be combined with a 3 to give 2+2 instead.

Without derivatives, you can replace any number k above 4 by 2(k-2).  So the best answer has no number above 4.

You can also replace 4 by 2*2, and have an answer with just 2s and 3s.  Now look for a way to replace 2s with 3s.

Comment: Oh, I did miss that. The optimum product should be $2^2\cdot3^{673}$ then.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the problem statement carefully, this turns out to be a bit less simple: The problem statement clearly says that $S$ is a **set**, not a family or multiset or list or whatnot. Therefore all attempts that suggest to have repeated elements, e.g., several copies of 2 or 3, are solutions to a different problem!

---

Let $S$ be a maximizing set (which exists because there are only finitely many sets of positive integer with fixed sum). Let $a=\min S$.

If $a=2k+1$ is odd with $k\ge 2$ (i.e., $a\ge 5$), then $S':=(S\setminus\{a\})\cup \{k,k+1\}$ is "better" because $k\cdot(k+1)=k^2+k\ge 3k>a$.

If $a=2k$ is even with $k\ge 3$ (i.e., $a\ge 6$), then
$S':=(S\setminus\{a\})\cup \{k-1,k+1\}$ is "better" because $(k-1)(k+1)=k^2-1>3k-1>2k$.

We conclude that $a\le 4$.

Suppose there are $b,c\in S$ such that $c\ge b+3$ and $b+1,c-1\notin S$.
Then $(S\setminus\{b,c\})\cup\{b+1,c-1\}$ is better because
$(b+1)(c-1)=bc+c-b-1\ge bc+2$.

We conclude that $S$ is a set of consecutive integers,
$$\tag1\{a,a+1,a+2,\ldots,m\}\qquad \text{with }a\le 4, a\le m,$$
or a set of consecutive integers with a single gap,
$$\tag2\{a,a+1,a+2,\ldots,t-1,t+1,t+2,\ldots,m\}\qquad \text{with }a\le 4,  a<t< m.$$
In variant $(1)$, we have
$$2023=\sum_{s\in S}s=\frac{m(m+1)}2-\frac{a(a-1)}2 = \frac{m(m+1)}2-(0\text{ or }1\text{ or }3\text{ or }6)$$
If $m\le 63$, the right hand side is $\le \frac{63\cdot 64}2=2016$; and if $m\ge 64$, it is $\ge \frac{64\cdot 65}2-6=2074$. We conclude that variant $(1)$ produces no maximizing set $S$.

So let's deal with variant $(2)$. If $a=4$, then $(S\setminus\{4,t+1\})\cup \{2,3,t\}$ is better because $6t>4(t+1)$. Hence $a\le 3$.
This makes
$$ \begin{aligned}2023&=\sum_{s\in S}s=\frac{m(m+1)}2-\frac{a(a-1)}2-t \\
&= \frac{m(m+1)}2-t-(0\text{ or }1\text{ or }3)\\
&\begin{cases}\ge \frac{m(m+1)}2-(m-1)-3=\frac{m^2-m-4}{2}\\
\le \frac{m(m+1)}2-2=\frac{m^2+m-4}2\end{cases}
\end{aligned}$$
If $m\ge 65$, then $\frac{m^2-m-4}2\ge 2078$; and if $m\le 63$, then $\frac{m^2+m-4}2\le 2014$. We conclude that $m=64$.
Then $t+\frac{a(a-1)}2 = \frac{m(m+1)}2-2023=57$ and
$$\prod_{s\in S}=\frac{m!}{(a-1)!t},  $$ so we are left with the following possibilities:
\begin{array}ra&t&(a-1)!t\\
1&57&57\\
2&56&56\\
3&54&110\\
\end{array}
We read off that the maximum is achieved in the second row, i.e, with
$$S=\{2,3,\ldots,54, 55,57,58,\ldots, 64\} $$
and
$$\prod_{s\in S}s = \frac{64!}{56} \approx 2.2658\cdot10^{87}. $$

Comment: The problem does say "set"; but the poster's analysis makes it clear that a multiset is what's intended, no?

Comment: I am sorry for the ambiguous problem statement, the repetition of elements was allowed. But this post answers a very similar problem, albeit more difficult, so I really think you should keep it here.